# Cast Date and Timestamp in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-notebooks

I have an i/p file which is coming in a csv format where date and timestamp  are coming as String in the fromat mm/dd/yy and yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS.

I am writing a parquet file and converting to date and timestamp format with the below code.

```
if k == 'Date':
    data = data.withColumn(c, to_date(data[c],'MM/dd/yyyy'))
else:
    if k == 'Timestamp':
        data = data.withColumn(c, to_timestamp(data[c],'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'))
```

But in the o/p date is getting written in YYYY-MM-DD and timestamp is being written in the format
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format.

Is there a way I can write the o/p as date and timestamp datatype with the format MM/dd/yyyy and yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS

Need the o/p in format 07/24/2007 and 2007-07-24-14.45.09.811306 with storing them as date and timestampo datatype. But they are coming as 2007-07-24 and 2007-07-24 14:45:09 when I cast them.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question, please edit the question to include some sample data and as a minimum explain how you expect the data to be displayed.

Comment: Have edited the post with the required fromat

Comment: There is such thing as `elif` (else if) if the else of your initial if has just that one criteria.

Comment: What part of provide sample data and show example of how you would like result displayed, didn't you understand?

Comment: Sample I/p data- 07/24/2007 and 2007-07-24-14.45.09.811306

Comment: Expected o/p data - 07/24/2007 and 2007-07-24-14.45.09.811306 . Data type is date and timestamp instead of string

Comment: But what is your input data type? Is it string?

Comment: Yes I/p is string

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach in pyspark to convert the string format to desired date format and timestamp format:

**Input Data:**

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, to_timestamp, date_format
csv_file_path = "abfss://folder02@dilipstgsynp.dfs.core.windows.net/smpl.csv"
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(csv_file_path)
df = df.withColumn("date1", to_date("date1", "MM/dd/yyyy"))
df = df.withColumn("date2", to_timestamp("date2", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS"))
df = df.withColumn("date1", date_format("date1", "MM/dd/yyyy"))
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Results:**

```
root |-- date1: string (nullable = true) |-- date2: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

[image]
In the above code converting the "**date1**" column from string format to a DateType format using the `to_date` function.

Converting the "**date2**" column from string format to a TimestampType format using the `to_timestamp` function.
The second argument "**yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS**" specifies the format of the input string that represents the timestamp.

Reformating the "**date1**" column to the  output format '**MM/dd/yyyy**' using the date_format function.

I have tried Casting the String datatype to date datatype

```
df = df.withColumn("date1", to_date(date_format(col("date1"), "MM/dd/yyyy"), "MM/dd/yyyy").cast("date"))
```

[image]